# give property a type when using object destructuring from a js file

Tags: typescript

I am declaring an object apiClient like so:

```
const { apiClient } : any = useAuth();
```

Is there anyway that I can declare the type of apiClient so I can use intellisense?

I tried

```
const { apiClient } : { apiClient : JsonServiceClient } = useAuth();
```

But get error:
`Property 'apiClient' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ apiClient: JsonServiceClient; }'.ts(2741)`

useAuth() is declared in a normal js file so it doesn't have a return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
const { apiClient } = useAuth() as { apiClient : JsonServiceClient };
```